# How can i access the new value of a variable once it is passed through an if else clause in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was creating a code in which by default the reference is in drivers node and changes to customer if snapshot doesn't exist but the issue is it isn't changing. When I looked at the code I realized that the variable is not being used so I was wondering if there is anyway to do it.
here is my code

```
auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        button=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Fixmail = findViewById(R.id.fixedemail);
        password=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        DatabaseReference uidRef = reference.child("Driver").child(uid); //this variable
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {//TODO find how to change uidRef
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    Users usersnapshot = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                    if (usersnapshot != null) {
                        String Email = usersnapshot.getMail();
                        Fixmail.setText(Email);
                    }
                } else {
                    final DatabaseReference uidRef=reference.child("Customer").child(uid);
                    Users usersnapshot = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                    if (usersnapshot != null) {
                        String Email = usersnapshot.getMail();
                        Fixmail.setText(Email);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-assign that variable in the context you're in; local variables must be `final` or *effectively final* in order to be used within an anonymous class.

Even if you could, `uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent` would be called *before* the new value is captured. The new value would not register the listener, since you never re-add the listener to the new value.

---

First, you'd remove the local uidRef you created in the else block, to avoid shadowing issues.

In the else block, you would remove the listener from the original `uidRef` (which is currently Driver - that would remove the listener from driver). You could do that via

```
uidRef.removeValueListener(this)
```

Then, you'd obtain the child you want (Customer) and add the listener to the new child.

You can do that via

```
reference.child("Customer").child(uid).addListenerForSingleValue(this)
```